# UseHttpsRedirection not working reliably?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

The default startup code created for my ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application includes the following code:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

This seems to be hit or miss. Right now, on my development machine, editing the URL in the address bar so it uses HTTP instead of HTTPS gives me a *The connection was reset* error.

Also, I found the `AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()` option, which can be passed to `app.UseRewriter()`.

At this point, I'm unclear why `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` doesn't appear to work, or if I should be using `UseRewriter()`.

Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: have you seen [this arcticle](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopingLocallyWithASPNETCoreUnderHTTPSSSLAndSelfSignedCerts.aspx) about trusting the ASP.NET Core development SSL certificate? Another thing to check is running VS (or whatever IDE you use) as Admin and see if you get the same thing

Comment: @GlynnHurrell: By default, my project runs in HTTPS on my development machine. That's why I tried changing it to HTTP to see what happened. Maybe I don't get your point.

Comment: No, you're quit right I missed your point. Doh!

Answer (score 8):

#### TL;DR:

The redirect works as expected. `HTTP` and `HTTPS` use different ports.

By only removing the `s` from the url: `https://localhost:44336`, your are trying to do `HTTP` to an application port that expects `HTTPS`, which is not supported. For the redirect to work, you need to contact the `HTTP` port, using `HTTP`.

Using the designated `HTTP` url, `http://localhost:53640`, you'll see the application redirects as expected.

In my example, see `launchSettings.json` it's defined as follows:

```
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53640"
```

---

So whats happening here is the following:

#### In general

- A "HTTPS port"<sup>*</sup>, only accepts HTTPS (,so no HTTP) connections.
- A "HTTP port"<sup>*</sup>, only accepts HTTP (,so no HTTPS) connections.

<sup>* in physical world there is no such thing as a HTTPS or HTTP port, since it's defined at [level 7 OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).</sup>

The `UseHttpsRedirection`, routes inbound HTTP traffic, on the HTTP port to HTTPS traffic on the HTTPS port.

When an URL in a browser does not specify a port number,  it defaults to the port typically used by the protocol. Being port 80 for HTTP, and 443 for HTTPS.

#### The debugger case

To prevent port collisions, Visual Studio uses non standard ports by default to debug. You can see them in the 'launchSettings.json` file.

Mine looks like this:

```
 "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53640",
      "sslPort": 44336
    }
  },
```

Note the 2 port numbers. The redirect only works at (and to) the designated ports.

HTTP is accepted at 53640, HTTPS is accepted at 44336.

#### Your use-case

By changing removing the `s` in the URL bar, you are changing:

> https://localhost:44336

to

> http://localhost:44336

Note, since you did not adjust the port, you're trying to connect with HTTP on a HTTPS port. This scenario is not covered by the redirect and *will fail.*

Only `http://localhost:53640` will redirect to `https://localhost:44336`. Just HTTP: `http://localhost:44336` will result in a connection reset.

#### The production server case

In normal circumstances, you release your application to a webserver, using the default ports (80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS, with appropriate certificate).

Since the browser the user is using also uses these default ports, the redirect works well, since:

> http://example.org will actually translate to http://example.org:80 and
> https://example.org will translate to https://example.org:443

and thus, this will magically work out of the box:

> http://example.org:80
> will redirect to
> https://example.org:443

The browser just doesn't show the port numbers.
To locate the `launchSettings.json` file: The file in VS:

[image]

---

#### Alternatively

If that doesn't help, possibly the order of `app.Use...` is wrong.

Basically it are extensions registering middleware. The order is important.

Normally, initially the redirect is configured, afterward MVC. Like so:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 
app.UseMvc();
app.UseOtherMiddleWare();
```

If you reverse the order, possibly you'll hit an error earlier in the pipeline and the redirect is not executed.

Comment: Well, the Visual Studio Wizards decided where `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` was placed. Also, I'm not using `app.UseMvc()` in Razor Pages applications.